# Dynamically generated html, document.getElementByID returns null

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am generating an html table dynamically in my code behind file

```
    protected void PopulateMemberTable()
    {
        var guid = "";
        string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "MEMBID", "MEMBER_NAME", "BIRTH", "IPA", "HPNAME" };
        if (Session["guid"] != null)
            guid = Session["guid"].ToString();
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        DataTable dt = MemberSearch(guid, membFirst.Text.ToString(), membLast.Text.ToString(), membDob.Text.ToString(), membId.Text.ToString());
        if (dt != null)
        {
            DataTable new_dt = new DataView(dt).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);        
            html.Append("<table class='table table-hover data-table'>");
            html.Append("<thead>");
            html.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in new_dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                switch(column.ColumnName.ToString())
                {
                    case "MEMBID":
                        html.Append("Member ID");
                        break;
                    case "MEMBER_NAME":
                        html.Append("Member Name");
                        break;
                    case "BIRTH":
                        html.Append("DOB");
                        break;
                    case "IPA":
                        html.Append("IPA");
                        break;
                    case "HPNAME":
                        html.Append("Health Plan");
                        break;
                }
                html.Append("</th>");

            }
            //btn column (no header)
            html.Append("<th></th>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
            html.Append("</thead>");
            html.Append("<tbody>");
            var counter = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in new_dt.Rows)
            {
                counter++;
                string btnId = "\"" + "<%btnMembGrid" + counter.ToString() + ".ClientId%>" + "\"";
                html.Append("<tr onclick='document.getElementById(" + btnId + ").click()'>");
                var btnValue = new StringBuilder();                  
                foreach(DataColumn column in new_dt.Columns)
                {             
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    btnValue.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    btnValue.Append(";");
                    html.Append("</td>");  
                }
                html.Append("<td><asp:button runat='server' OnClick='selectMember' CssClass='btn btn-default' style='display:none' value = '"
                    + btnValue.ToString() + "' id= 'btnMembGrid" + counter.ToString() +  "'/></td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
            html.Append("</tbody>");
            html.Append("</table>");
        }
        else
            html.Append("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>No Members Found</div>");

        membTable.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });

    }
```

The table is generated just fine, but now I am trying to call some server side code when a row is clicked

```
            foreach (DataRow row in new_dt.Rows)
            {
                counter++;
                string btnId = "\"" + "<%btnMembGrid" + counter.ToString() + ".ClientId%>" + "\"";
                html.Append("<tr onclick='document.getElementById(" + btnId + ").click()'>");
                var btnValue = new StringBuilder();                  
                foreach(DataColumn column in new_dt.Columns)
                {             
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    btnValue.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    btnValue.Append(";");
                    html.Append("</td>");  
                }
                html.Append("<td><asp:button runat='server' OnClick='selectMember' CssClass='btn btn-default' style='display:none' value = '"
                    + btnValue.ToString() + "' id= 'btnMembGrid" + counter.ToString() +  "'/></td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
```

I attempted to accomplish this task by placing a hidden `<asp:Button/>` in each row and then adding a corresponding `onclick` attribute to each `<tr>` tag

This is how the generated html looks like in the dev console

[image]

However when I attempt to click the row I get the following error message

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate some input, or possibly even an alternative approach.

Comment: Part of your mistake is trying to create aspnet Button Controls as a string and expecting them to work. You need dynamically created controls to do that.

Comment: Have you thought about using a repeater to generate the table instead of the code behind?  I don't think your asp button is added as a control so it might not be accessible in the same way as if you wrote it directly into the markup.  Also I think you want the `<%` script tag to be a `<%=` (Response.Write) tag.

Comment: And if you create html tables in code behind, perhaps a `GridView` or other type of Control would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out that passing an `<asp:button/>` as a string wasn't going to work, I took an alternative approach.

In `populateMemberTable()`I added an href attribute to the first column in each row

```
                var href = true;              
                foreach(DataColumn column in new_dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    if (href)
                    {
                        href = false;
                        html.Append("<a href='/default.aspx?guid=" + Session["guid"] + "&membid=" + row[column.ColumnName]  +"'>");
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        html.Append("</a></td>");
                    }                        
                    else
                    {
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        btnValue.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        btnValue.Append(";");
                        html.Append("</td>");
                    }

                }
```

And then I saved the membId as a session variable in `Page_Load()`

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //save guid (http://url.com?guid=xxxxxx) as session variable 
        Session["guid"] = Request.QueryString["guid"];
        var membId = Request.QueryString["membid"];
        if (membId != null)
        {
            Session["membid"] = membId;
        }

    }
```

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it got me what I needed and was straightforward to implement. Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and use the delegation model to handle click on dynamic elements. if for example you have some html like

```
<div id="dynamicname'></div>
```

then use 
the jquery code snippet

```
$(document).on('click','#dynamicname',function(){
//handle your event here 
});
```

dynamic html should always be handled by delegation model. And you can use

```
var dynamic_name="#"+getYourDynamicRowName;//variable for dynamic id's of dynamic html element
  $(document).on('click',dynamic_name,function(){
    //handle your event here 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience we can not use asp tag while you are creating dynamic HTML.

If you see your code of dev console you can see that controls are not rendered properly..rendered with asp tag..

To achieve it you can use javascript/Jquery to call server side function.

```
<input type="button" ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="fn();" />
```

And in your javascript:

```
fn = function(){
    __doPostBack("<%=btn.ClientID%>", "");
}
```

And in your code:
`

```
protected override void btnEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the button event 
    //base.btnEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == btn)
    {
         //do some logic
    }
}
```